# Add parent row as a column identifier in R

Tags: r

I have an export of a data which lists a hierarchical structure but it's not really usable for my purposes. Here is an example of the data:

| Level | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CO123 |
| 2 | PN123 |
| 2 | PN124 |
| 1 | CO124 |
| 2 | PN125 |
| 2 | PN126 |
| 1 | CO125 |
| 2 | PN127 |
| 2 | PN128 |

I want it to look like this:

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| CO123 | PN123 |
| CO123 | PN124 |
| CO124 | PN125 |
| CO124 | PN126 |
| CO125 | PN127 |
| CO125 | PN128 |

I have a lot more rows with varying amounts of "children" for each parent. However, the parent only shows up in the data set once, while the children could be structured to multiple parents.

I'm trying to run some analysis on each parent, like the average number of children.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `pivot_wider` to reshape to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(nm1 = case_when(Level == 1 ~ "Parent", TRUE ~ "Child"),
    rn = rowid(Level)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = nm1, values_from = Number) %>%  
  fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>% 
  filter(Level != 1) %>%
   select(-rn,-Level)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Parent Child
  <chr>  <chr>
1 CO123  PN123
2 CO123  PN124
3 CO124  PN125
4 CO124  PN126
5 CO125  PN127
6 CO125  PN128
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Level = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
    Number = c("CO123", "PN123", "PN124", "CO124", "PN125", "PN126", 
    "CO125", "PN127", "PN128")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun, that worked but I'm just wondering what's the purpose of the distinct at the end? When I run it on my data I get the same output running it with and without it.

Comment: @MattSimonson you need to assign i.e. `out <- df1 %>%...` and then check `out`.  It is because there are some duplicate elements from `fill`

Comment: @akrun You might also need to add a `filter` statement after `fill`, but before removing `Level`, as this creates an additional row from the parent. I think it should have 6 rows rather than 8.

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `tidyverse` using `fill` and `filter`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Parent = ifelse(Level == 1, Number, NA)) %>% 
  fill(Parent, .direction = "down") %>% 
  filter(Level != 1) %>% 
  select(Parent, Child = Number)
```

**Output**

```
  Parent Child
1  CO123 PN123
2  CO123 PN124
3  CO124 PN125
4  CO124 PN126
5  CO125 PN127
6  CO125 PN128
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Level = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
    Number = c("CO123", "PN123", "PN124", "CO124", "PN125", "PN126", 
    "CO125", "PN127", "PN128")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer differs from the others because it is an attempt to implement a more general approach to handle multiple levels. Namely, the approach consists in finding the closest row with `level` less than current `level`

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2), V2 = c("CO123", 
"PN123", "PN124", "CO124", "PN125", "PN126", "CO125", "PN127", 
"PN128")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

attach(df)

m <- outer(V1, V1, "<")

which(m & upper.tri(m), arr.ind = TRUE) |>
  data.frame() |>
  group_by(col) |>
  summarize(row = max(row)) |>
  transmute(parent = V2[row],
            child = V2[col])


##> # A tibble: 6 × 2
##>   parent child
##>   <chr>  <chr>
##> 1 CO123  PN123
##> 2 CO123  PN124
##> 3 CO124  PN125
##> 4 CO124  PN126
##> 5 CO125  PN127
##> 6 CO125  PN128
```

It also works on a multi-level hierarchy e.g.:

```r
h <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,2,3,3,2,3,3,2,2,1,2,3),
                V2 = toupper(letters[1:12]))

h

##>    V1 V2
##> 1   1  A
##> 2   2  B
##> 3   3  C
##> 4   3  D
##> 5   2  E
##> 6   3  F
##> 7   3  G
##> 8   2  H
##> 9   2  I
##> 10  1  J
##> 11  2  K
##> 12  3  L

attach(h)
m <- outer(V1, V1, "<")


which(m & upper.tri(m), arr.ind = TRUE) |>
  data.frame() |>
  group_by(col) |>
  summarize(row = max(row)) |>
  transmute(parent = V2[row],
            child = V2[col])

##> # A tibble: 10 × 2
##>    parent child
##>    <chr>  <chr>
##>  1 A      B    
##>  2 B      C    
##>  3 B      D    
##>  4 A      E    
##>  5 E      F    
##>  6 E      G    
##>  7 A      H    
##>  8 A      I    
##>  9 J      K    
##> 10 K      L
```